# WPF UserControl works in WPF app, but with BindingSource in Winforms app w/ElementHost, setters are never called

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, data-binding, elementhost

This Winforms app works fine, but I'm now trying to add a bound WPF UserControl to it via ElementHost, and my attempts at binding it have no effect.

Left two thirds of screen capture are normal databound Winforms controls. Right third of screen capture is my WPF UserControl (which houses a ToolBar, RichTextBox, and a (strictly for debugging, will be removed later) plain TextBox.)

**Expected Result:** When I switch projects in leftmost pane, (WPF) "HelloText" should be replaced with the text seen in the Problem Statement" (Winforms) TextBox.

**Actual Result:** "HelloText" never changes.

1. Yes, my domain object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. Yes, I implemented "Text" and "Document" `DependencyProperty`ies in the root of the WPF UserControl that *do* modify the inner controls' values (works when written to in my throwaway WPF tester app, but not the Winforms app seen in the screen capture.)
3. I adapted my Winforms-to-WPF binding code from the accepted solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12054082/2112855
4. Breakpoints in the WPF UC's setters are never hit when running the Winforms app.

[image: screen capture]

```cs
            System.Windows.Data.Binding wpfb2 = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("ProblemStatement") // WPF
            {
                Source = _bs,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };   
            rteProblemStatement.SetBinding(WpfRichTextEditor.RichTextEditor.TextProperty, wpfb2);
```

Comment: IMO, it's better to add the DataBinding to the ElementHost and use its `PropertyMap` to add a `PropertyTranslator` delegate, to set the Text property of the WPF Control using the value passed by the delegate. To add a a Binding to the ElementHost, use  the standard `[ElementHost].DataBindings.Add("Text", [The BindingSource instance], "ProblemStatement", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);` then add the delegate: `[ElementHost].PropertyMap.Add("Text", new PropertyTranslator(OnTextChanged));`, where `OnTextChanged` is the method delegate that receives the string value to set.

Comment: Otherwise, you can probably add a ViewModel to the UC and use its public properties as a *map* for the Properties you want to bind (the DataContext is set to the ViewModel object).

Comment: This being my first exposure to ElementHost, I wasn't even aware of the existence of PropertyTranslator :/ But yeah, that worked :) Upgrade your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Can PropertyTranslator round-trip this (write edited text back to the domain object)?

Comment: (Google is of no help here. Searching for [winforms "propertymap" "two way"] gives about a dozen garbage hits.)